# How to insert a meteor template into summernote editor?

Tags: templates, meteor, datacontext, summernote

I need a button that insert my meteor template into summernote editor. 
I have a custom summernote button:

```
    var MyButton = function (context) {
    var ui = $.summernote.ui;
    var button = ui.button({
        contents: 'MyButton',

        click: function () {
            var node = document.createElement('span');
            node.innerHTML = '{{>myTemplate}}'
            context.invoke('editor.insertNode', node);
            },
        });
    return button.render();
```

But instead of html I only get "{{>myTemplate}}" as string. 
Should I re-render the editor or something?

Comment: You might be interested in [Blaze.toHTML](http://blazejs.org/api/blaze.html#Blaze-toHTML) but beware of that it is not reactive.

Comment: and no events attached with Blaze.toHTML